# ui-boostrap $modal causes Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm new to angularjs and ui-bootstrap 13 and need some help.

I'm getting a unresolved from thew angularjs injector and can't figure out why.

The module definition looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('MobileCOP', [
"ngRoute",
"ngTouch",
"mobile-angular-ui",
"ui.bootstrap"]);
```

The controller looks like this:

```
app.controller('CDRserver',['$rootScope','$scope','$location','serverList','$modal',

    function($rootScope, $scope, $location, serverList, $modal ){
```

All I need to do to cause the error is inject $modal into the controller. I don't reference the modal in the code, just adding the modal service to the controller causes the issue. When the service is removed the error stops.

I'm assuming I'm missing something obvious.

Edit" As per request showing the controller assignment into the html:

.when('/cdrquery', {
    templateUrl: '/MobileCOP/tmpl/CDRlist.html',
    controller: 'CDRList'
})

Error:

```
[$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/unpr?p0=%24templateRequestProvider%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24modal
z/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:6:450
Zb/l.$injector<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:34:1
c@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:33:83
Zb/q.$injector<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:35:57
c@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:33:83
d@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:33:300
Zb/q.$injector<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:35:75
c@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:33:83
d@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:33:300
f/<.instantiate@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:33:464
Md/this.$get</<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:65:484
z/<.link@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular-route.min.js:7:248
J@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:52:492
h@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:46:28
ba/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:45:200
Z/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:46:431
q@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:50:162
v@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular-route.min.js:6:357
Wd/this.$get</h.prototype.$broadcast@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:110:279
l/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular-route.min.js:11:177
ve/e/l.promise.then/H@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:96:513
ve/e/l.promise.then/H@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:96:513
ve/f/<.then/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:98:173
Wd/this.$get</h.prototype.$eval@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:108:36
Wd/this.$get</h.prototype.$digest@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:105:323
Wd/this.$get</h.prototype.$apply@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:108:368
g@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:71:118
C@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:75:241
re/</y.onreadystatechange@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:76:280
<ng-view class="app-content ng-scope">
```

Loading scripts code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular-touch.min.js"></script>

<script src="/MobileCOP/libs/mobile-angular-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/MobileCOP/libs/ui-bootstrap-0.13.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Required to use $touch, $swipe, $drag and $translate services -->
<script src="/MobileCOP/libs/mobile-angular-ui.gestures.min.js"></script>
<script src="/MobileCOP/libs/xml2json.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you show the order that your scripts are being loaded in the HTML?

Comment: please attach an error. E.g. it can be lack of tpl file for ui.bootstrap

Comment: that's not the HTML where your scripts are loaded, that's a random piece of javascript routing code showing your template URL.  The error you are experiencing is most commonly caused because you refer to the `<script>` tags in the incorrect order.  show the **HTML** where your `<script>` tags are.

Comment: i think the load order is correct.. the angularjs code looks in the correct order.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are not using a template enabled version of the ui-bootstrap libraries.  From the ui-bootstrap [FAQ](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/FAQ#im-using-modal-service-but-it-cant-find-its-templates):

> The dist files with the  -tpls-  in their name come with the templates bundled inside  $templateCache . You can check how this bundling works by inspecting [this file](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js#L3950). The important point here is that templates are part of the distribution file so you don't need to download them separately. Also, those templates are pre-loaded with JS file so a browser won't request them on run-time.

bottom line, for template enabled modules like modal to work, you need to be loading the script `ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js`.

The error you are getting is coming from the `templateRequestProvider` when it looks for a template for `$modal` that isn't in the template cache.

Comment: Changed over to  ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js.  Same issue.. I was trying to track down the source of the error.. I did notice the template error.. I was a bit confused about it since the modal was not instantiated.

Comment: OK cleared up the issue.. ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js is incompatible with angularjs 1.2.15. Upgraded to 1.3.14, the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

OK cleared up the issue.. ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js is incompatible with angularjs 1.2.15. Upgraded to 1.3.14, the error is gone.